# Android. Can't install developed APK on phone when Ok on emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am developing android application under Eclipse. It is running in emulator just fine under different platforms. I have checked android version on friend's telephone, also in eclipse and successfully ran it on emulator too. Created unsigned application package using eclipse. 
Installing on phone.
After installation he got error message "app not installed" and button 'Done'. Uninstaller found my program and got error '%program name% failed: invalid URI'. In my xml files I didn;t see nothing that can help with this error.. What does it mean? :(

Comment: 9 month, 9 questions and still not one answer accepted. I am wondering what you should improve...

Comment: Did you turn on debugging and unknown sources on the phone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An unsigned apk can't be installed anywhere.

You have three solutions:

1. go into the `bin` folder and use the apk that is stored there (this apk is signed with your debug certificate)
2. connect the phone via usb to your pc and install it using eclipse (Run as -> Android Application -> select the device)
3. Create a signed application. You need a valid keystore for that (Eclipse helps you creating one)

Tips at the end: Give the community something back by accept answers on your previous questions!

Comment: Thank you for response! I remember someday tried to accept answers, but it didn't help. Will try again.